# Jest test coverage vs watch

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I seem to get different results in the summary chart when I run

```
npm test -- --coverage
```

versus when I run

```
npm test -- --coverage --watch
```

The *watched* version only shows 1 test total (suites related to changed files). However it also shows all the files in the summary chart (with worse stats)

I'm wondering if the chart is cached or something? I'm not sure why there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

After you run `npm test -- --coverage --watch` press `a` to run all tests.

Comment: Yes that will produce a summary chart with the same results as not running with `--watch`. However, I still don't understand why running with both `--watch` and `--coverage` produce similar summary charts (with _all_ files) but with different results.